# Is there a way to remove xml doc of internalized methods when using ILmerge?

Tags: obfuscation, ilmerge, xml-documentation

I have multiple assemblies for a library that I merge into a single assembly with ILmerge, using the `/internalize` flag. Additionally I also merge the xml docs generated by the compiler into a file using the `/xmldocs`.

The following question may sound bizarre but there is a reason behind:
Is there a way to remove the internalized methods documentation from the documentation xml?

Why? Because in a second step, I obfuscate the merged assembly. All internal methods are going to be renamed/modified and the documentation is therefore useless and even worse: it does reveal information about the obfuscated part.